# Selenium IDE - There was an unexpected Confirmation!

Tags: testing, selenium

I have a button that displays Javascript confirmation popup. This is a part of my test case:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>buttonId</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Object has been deleted</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

It works as expected: OK is clicked automatically on a popup and `verifyTextPresent` return true. Still, I get `[error] There was an unexpected Confirmation!` in the log and test case fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "javascript confirmation popup" > an alert? a confirm? a custom dialog window? a pop-up window?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Summary: In the IDE use storeConfirmation.

You have to consume confirmation dialogs. Otherwise the Selenium test will fail.

From the Java Selenium RC API [Selenium.html.getConfirmation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getConfirmation%28%29) method:

> If a confirmation is generated but
> you do not consume it with
> getConfirmation method, the next Selenium
> action will fail.

**Edit:**

[storeConfirmation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storeConfirmation) consumes the confirmation as well.

> **storeConfirmation ( variableName )**
>
> Retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog
> generated during the previous action.
>
> If a confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with
> getConfirmation method, the next Selenium
> action will fail.

Comment: But how can I do this from Selenium IDE (firefox plugin)? There is no command like getConfirmation available there.

Comment: Thats this was the perfect answer for me.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem, and I solved it like this:

chooseOkOnNextConfirmation
click buttonId
assertConfirmation

This makes my test run green in my Selenium IDE.

The code to do this is:

```
<tr>
    <td>chooseOkOnNextConfirmation</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>ctl00_CPHMain_ucFormDMS_grdDocumentList_ctl00_ctl04_btnDelete</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertConfirmation</td>
    <td>Areyousureyouwanttodeletethisdocument?</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If iam getting next to next confirmation as first to cancel and then to ok on confirmation, what should i do?

Comment: I don't have the project available anymore so I can't help you now :(

Answer (score 1):

using selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation is correct but insead of using this alone use

`selenium.click("xpath=//button");
selenium.getConfirmation();
selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();`

Here it will first click on the button and get the confirmation , then it would click OK from that confirmation

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium IDE you can use **waitForConfirmation(pattern)**